# Can I create an AWS state machine using the CDK for Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cdk, cdktf

I've been following the instructions [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/cdktf-build?in=terraform/cdktf) to stand up a new cdktf java project.  My current goal is to build a process that can create AWS state machine using a fluent-like syntax that I can then deploy to via terraform.  It seems like cdktf is what I need, but I'm unable to find any examples using cdktf and the [aws cdk for state machine tasks](https://constructs.dev/packages/@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks/v/1.151.0?lang=java#startqueryexecution).  Is it possible using cdktf to accomplish my goal?  What other pieces do I need to include/import in my project in order to build state machines?

Comment: "AWS CDK for Terraform" is not a thing. There's "AWS CDK", and "CDK for Terraform". They are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @gshpychka pointed out AWS CDK and CDK for Terraform (CDKTF) are different, there is an [interoperability layer](https://github.com/hashicorp/cdktf-aws-cdk) that you could try to use, it even has a [StepFunction example](https://github.com/hashicorp/cdktf-aws-cdk/blob/main/examples/typescript-step-functions/main.ts).